# Solr 6.4.1 Update very long

Tags: performance, insert-update, solr6

Solr 6.4.1 Take very long time to update. I have Solr 6.4.1. About 600 000 documents indexed.

When I do an update it takes about 20 to 60 seconds. Blocking my app (web page) for too long time.

- Solr Logs doesn't show anything like not enough memory or other.
- Search is pretty fast. (I search and index on same machine)
- There is not a lot of search queries (maybe 20 / mins)
- There is ony Postgresql runing on this machine with solr.

My Machine:

```
1x Intel Quad-Core Xeon E3-1230V2 [ 4 Core(s) ]
RAM 16 GB
120 GB SSD
```

My solrconfig.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>6.4.1</luceneMatchVersion>
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>
  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>
  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>
  <indexConfig>
    <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>
  </indexConfig>
  <jmx />
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
      <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
    </updateLog>
    <autoCommit>
      <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs> <!-- maximum uncommited docs before autocommit triggered -->
      <maxTime>600000</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>

    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>15000</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>
  </updateHandler>
  <query>
    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="4096"
                 initialSize="1024"
                 autowarmCount="1024"/>
    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                      size="4096"
                      initialSize="1024"
                      autowarmCount="512"/>
    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="4096"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/>

    <!-- custom cache currently used by block join -->
    <cache name="perSegFilter"
           class="solr.search.LRUCache"
           size="10"
           initialSize="0"
           autowarmCount="10"
           regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator" />

    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
    <queryResultWindowSize>40</queryResultWindowSize>

    <!-- Maximum number of documents to cache for any entry in the
         queryResultCache. 
      -->
    <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <!--
           <lst><str name="q">solr</str><str name="sort">price asc</str></lst>
           <lst><str name="q">rocks</str><str name="sort">weight asc</str></lst>
          -->
      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <!--
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </arr>
    </listener>

    <!-- Use Cold Searcher

         If a search request comes in and there is no current
         registered searcher, then immediately register the still
         warming searcher and use it.  If "false" then all requests
         will block until the first searcher is done warming.
      -->
    <useColdSearcher>true</useColdSearcher>

  </query>

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                    addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>

    <!-- HTTP Caching

         Set HTTP caching related parameters (for proxy caches and clients).

         The options below instruct Solr not to output any HTTP Caching
         related headers
      -->
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>

  <requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults"><!-- 
      <str name="mlt.fl">title</str> -->
      <str name="mlt">true</str>
      <str name="mlt.mintf">1</str>
     <!--  <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>  -->
     <!--  <str name="mlt.minwl">4</str>  -->
      <!-- <str name="mlt.boost">true</str> -->
      <str name="mlt.count">100</str>
      <str name="mlt.match.include">false</str> 
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


<!-- Suggestions in search input -->
<!-- need call curl http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.build=true (put in cron)-->
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FreeTextLookupFactory</str> 
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">term_suggest</str>
    <str name="ngrams">3</str>
    <float name="threshold">0.004</float>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="separator"> </str>
    <str name="suggestFreeTextAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">phrase_suggest</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- A request handler that returns indented JSON by default -->
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


  <!-- A Robust Example

       This example SearchHandler declaration shows off usage of the
       SearchHandler with many defaults declared

       Note that multiple instances of the same Request Handler
       (SearchHandler) can be registered multiple times with different
       names (and different init parameters)
    -->
  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler" useParams="query,facets,velocity,browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <!-- Solr Cell Update Request Handler

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler 

    -->
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>

    <!-- Multiple "Spell Checkers" can be declared and used by this
         component
      -->

    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">_text_</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      -->
    </lst>

  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Term Vector Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent
    -->
  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the term vector component

       This is purely as an example.

       In reality you will likely want to add the component to your 
       already specified request handlers. 
    -->
  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Clustering Component. (Omitted here. See the default Solr example for a typical configuration.) -->

  <!-- Terms Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

       A component to return terms and document frequency of those
       terms
    -->
  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <!-- Query Elevation Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

       a search component that enables you to configure the top
       results for a given query regardless of the normal lucene
       scoring.
    -->
  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Highlighting Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters
    -->
  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap"
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
           (for sentence extraction) 
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex"
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html"
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html"
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single"
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default"
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <!-- 
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator"
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>

 <!-- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig#SchemaFactoryDefinitioninSolrConfig-Switchingfromschema.xmltoManagedSchema -->
  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>


  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
    <!-- UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory will generate an id if none is present in the incoming document -->
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="pattern">[^\w-\.]</str>
      <str name="replacement">_</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.ParseBooleanFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <arr name="format">
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd</str>
      </arr>
    </processor>
<!--     <processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
        <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
      </lst>
    </processor> -->
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
    <!-- For the purposes of the tutorial, JSON responses are written as
     plain text so that they are easy to read in *any* browser.
     If you expect a MIME type of "application/json" just remove this override.
    -->
    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <!--
     Custom response writers can be declared as needed...
    -->
  <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy">
    <str name="template.base.dir">${velocity.template.base.dir:}</str>
    <str name="solr.resource.loader.enabled">${velocity.solr.resource.loader.enabled:true}</str>
    <str name="params.resource.loader.enabled">${velocity.params.resource.loader.enabled:false}</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <!-- XSLT response writer transforms the XML output by any xslt file found
       in Solr's conf/xslt directory.  Changes to xslt files are checked for
       every xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds.  
    -->
  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>

</config>
```

Solr config:

```
java -server -Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/ssd/solr-6.4.1/server/logs/solr_gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=9 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -Dsolr.log.dir=/ssd/solr-6.4.1/server/logs -Djetty.port=8983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djetty.home=/ssd/solr-6.4.1/server -Dsolr.solr.home=/ssd/solr-6.4.1/server/solr -Dsolr.install.dir=/ssd/solr-6.4.1 -Xss256k -Dsolr.log.muteconsole -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/ssd/solr-6.4.1/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /ssd/solr-6.4.1/server/logs -jar start.jar --module=http
```

My Top:

```
top - 10:27:49 up 21 days,  1:26, 11 users,  load average: 1.96, 1.87, 1.62
Tasks: 255 total,   2 running, 253 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 16.5%us,  1.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 80.6%id,  1.4%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16302964k total, 13768272k used,  2534692k free,   109104k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,    54360k used,  4139940k free,  7578944k cached

  PID  PPID    TIME+  %CPU %MEM  PR  NI S  VIRT SWAP  RES  UID COMMAND
 6848     1 585:52.68  0.0 28.5  20   0 S 4619m  36m 4.4g  497 redis-server
28423     1   3:30.74 98.3  4.4  20   0 S 6655m    0 701m  501 java
28589 28569   0:11.55 98.3  0.4  20   0 R  272m    0  69m   26 postmaster
28603 28569   0:02.17 17.7  0.2  20   0 S  225m    0  30m   26 postmaster
28590 28569   0:01.30  0.0  0.2  20   0 S  218m    0  23m   26 postmaster
28605 28569   0:05.64  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  219m    0  23m   26 postmaster
28598 28569   0:01.88  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  217m    0  22m   26 postmaster
28601 28569   0:00.85  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  216m    0  22m   26 postmaster
28600 28569   0:03.71  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  216m    0  22m   26 postmaster
28599 28569   0:02.55  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  217m    0  21m   26 postmaster
28594 28569   0:02.18  3.9  0.1  20   0 S  217m    0  21m   26 postmaster
28569     1   0:00.01  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  206m    0  21m   26 postmaster
28604 28569   0:01.42  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  217m    0  21m   26 postmaster
28607 28569   0:00.43  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  212m    0  17m   26 postmaster
28608 28569   0:00.78  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  211m    0  16m   26 postmaster
28592 28569   0:11.66  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  210m    0  16m   26 postmaster
28610 28569   0:01.61  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  209m    0  15m   26 postmaster
28593 28569   0:00.15 15.7  0.1  20   0 S  209m    0  14m   26 postmaster
28595 28569   0:01.58  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  209m    0  14m   26 postmaster
28591 28569   0:12.55  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  14m   26 postmaster
28602 28569   0:24.07  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  14m   26 postmaster
28597 28569   0:11.68  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  14m   26 postmaster
28596 28569   0:00.65  3.9  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  14m   26 postmaster
28606 28569   0:00.23  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  13m   26 postmaster
28586 28569   0:00.07  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  13m   26 postmaster
28587 28569   0:00.09  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  13m   26 postmaster
28611 28569   0:00.18  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  12m   26 postmaster
28588 28569   0:00.06  0.0  0.1  20   0 S  208m    0  12m   26 postmaster
21377     1   0:00.64  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  172m    0 5924    0 tuned
31278     1   1:19.31  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  154m    0 5180    0 mosh-server
26481     1   0:01.48  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  155m    0 4132    0 mosh-server
25672  2148   0:00.00  0.0  0.0  20   0 S 80984    0 3440   89 pickup
26639     1   0:00.68  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  155m    0 3264    0 mosh-server
 1605     1   0:04.71  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  243m  300 3200    0 rsyslogd
 7324     1   0:05.83  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  154m    0 3128    0 mosh-server
26552     1   0:01.55  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  154m    0 2988    0 mosh-server
21349     1   0:00.00  0.0  0.0  20   0 S  118m    0 2820    0 pmqos-static.py
```

Info on a commit in the Log:

```
2017-03-13 09:32:36.787 INFO  (qtp1348949648-71) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [collection1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true}{add=[videos_manager.video.23228 (1561746500237656064)],commit=} 0 30773
2017-03-13 09:32:36.818 INFO  (qtp1348949648-68) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 start commit{,optimize=false,openSearcher=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false,softCommit=false,prepareCommit=false}
2017-03-13 09:32:36.818 INFO  (qtp1348949648-68) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.u.SolrIndexWriter Calling setCommitData with IW:org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter@49e5d032
2017-03-13 09:32:36.847 INFO  (qtp1348949648-85) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.c.S.Request [collection1]  webapp=/solr path=/mlt params={q=id:videos_manager.video.472654&fl=*,score&start=0&mlt.fl=text&fq=(is_offensive:(false)+AND+status:(online))&fq=django_ct:(videos_manager.video)&rows=60&wt=json} status=0 QTime=0
2017-03-13 09:32:36.963 INFO  (qtp1348949648-68) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.s.SolrIndexSearcher Opening [Searcher@2b0f0079[collection1] main]
2017-03-13 09:32:36.966 INFO  (qtp1348949648-68) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.u.DirectUpdateHandler2 end_commit_flush
```

Trying an update:

```
2017-03-13 08:02:41.640 INFO  (qtp1348949648-16) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [collection1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true}{add=[videos_manager.video.850182 (1561740853406334976)],commit=} 0 20864
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunatly I founded the answer pretty quickly. I can't tell wich one of these parameters is making it fast (I think it is autoCommit) but it is blazing fast actually (I followed some articles on solr optimization).

Here is the new solrconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>6.4.1</luceneMatchVersion>

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/clustering/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-clustering-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/langid/lib/" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-langid-\d.*\.jar" />

  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/contrib/velocity/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
  <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-velocity-\d.*\.jar" />
  <!-- an exact 'path' can be used instead of a 'dir' to specify a 
       specific jar file.  This will cause a serious error to be logged 
       if it can't be loaded.
    -->
  <!--
     <lib path="../a-jar-that-does-not-exist.jar" /> 
  -->

  <!-- Data Directory

       Used to specify an alternate directory to hold all index data
       other than the default ./data under the Solr home.  If
       replication is in use, this should match the replication
       configuration.
    -->
  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:}</dataDir>

  <directoryFactory name="DirectoryFactory"
                    class="${solr.directoryFactory:solr.NRTCachingDirectoryFactory}"/>

  <codecFactory class="solr.SchemaCodecFactory"/>

  <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       Index Config - These settings control low-level behavior of indexing
       Most example settings here show the default value, but are commented
       out, to more easily see where customizations have been made.

       Note: This replaces <indexDefaults> and <mainIndex> from older versions
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
  <indexConfig>
  </indexConfig>

  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
      <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
    </updateLog>

    <autoCommit>
      <maxDocs>15000</maxDocs>

      <!-- I suspect This make slow updates !!!!!!!
      <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
       -->

      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>


    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>

  </updateHandler>

  <query>
    <maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>

    <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache"
                 size="512"
                 initialSize="512"
                 autowarmCount="0"/> 


    <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                      size="512"
                      initialSize="512"
                      autowarmCount="0"/>

    <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache"
                   size="512"
                   initialSize="512"
                   autowarmCount="0"/> 

    <!-- custom cache currently used by block join -->
    <cache name="perSegFilter"
           class="solr.search.LRUCache"
           size="10"
           initialSize="0"
           autowarmCount="10"
           regenerator="solr.NoOpRegenerator" />

    <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>

    <queryResultWindowSize>40</queryResultWindowSize>

    <!-- Maximum number of documents to cache for any entry in the
         queryResultCache. 
      -->
    <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>

    <listener event="newSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <!--
           <lst><str name="q">solr</str><str name="sort">price asc</str></lst>
           <lst><str name="q">rocks</str><str name="sort">weight asc</str></lst>
          -->
      </arr>
    </listener>
    <listener event="firstSearcher" class="solr.QuerySenderListener">
      <arr name="queries">
        <!--
        <lst>
          <str name="q">static firstSearcher warming in solrconfig.xml</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </arr>
    </listener>

    <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>

    <maxWarmingSearchers>12</maxWarmingSearchers>

  </query>

  <requestDispatcher handleSelect="false" >
    <requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                    addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>

    <!-- HTTP Caching

         Set HTTP caching related parameters (for proxy caches and clients).

         The options below instruct Solr not to output any HTTP Caching
         related headers
      -->
    <httpCaching never304="true" />
  </requestDispatcher>


  <!-- Used for more likt this videos related -->
  <requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults"><!-- 
      <str name="mlt.fl">title</str> -->
      <str name="mlt">true</str>
      <str name="mlt.mintf">1</str>
     <!--  <str name="mlt.mindf">2</str>  -->
     <!--  <str name="mlt.minwl">4</str>  -->
      <!-- <str name="mlt.boost">true</str> -->
      <str name="mlt.count">100</str>
      <str name="mlt.match.include">false</str> 
      <str name="echoParams">all</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>


<!-- Suggestions in search input -->
<!-- need call curl http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?suggest.build=true (put in cron)-->
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FreeTextLookupFactory</str> 
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">term_suggest</str>
    <str name="ngrams">3</str>
    <float name="threshold">0.004</float>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="separator"> </str>
    <str name="suggestFreeTextAnalyzerFieldType">text_suggest</str>
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">phrase_suggest</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggest</str>
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>


  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
         will be overridden by parameters in the request
      -->
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <int name="rows">10</int>
      <str name="df">text</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- A request handler that returns indented JSON by default -->
  <requestHandler name="/query" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="wt">json</str>
      <str name="indent">true</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler" useParams="query,facets,velocity,browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <initParams path="/update/**,/query,/select,/tvrh,/elevate,/spell,/browse">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="df">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <initParams path="/update/**">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="update.chain">add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema</str>
    </lst>
  </initParams>

  <!-- Solr Cell Update Request Handler

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler 

    -->
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract"
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Spell Check

       The spell check component can return a list of alternative spelling
       suggestions.  

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent
    -->
  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>

    <!-- Multiple "Spell Checkers" can be declared and used by this
         component
      -->

    <!-- a spellchecker built from a field of the main index -->
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">_text_</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
      <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str>
      <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
      <float name="accuracy">0.5</float>
      <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
      <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
      <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
      <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
      <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
      <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
      <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
      <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
      <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
      <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
      <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
        <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
      -->
    </lst>

    <!-- a spellchecker that can break or combine words.  See "/spell" handler below for usage -->
    <!--
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
      <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
      <str name="field">name</str>
      <str name="combineWords">true</str>
      <str name="breakWords">true</str>
      <int name="maxChanges">10</int>
    </lst>
    -->
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the spellcheck component.  

       NOTE: This is purely as an example.  The whole purpose of the
       SpellCheckComponent is to hook it into the request handler that
       handles your normal user queries so that a separate request is
       not needed to get suggestions.

       IN OTHER WORDS, THERE IS REALLY GOOD CHANCE THE SETUP BELOW IS
       NOT WHAT YOU WANT FOR YOUR PRODUCTION SYSTEM!

       See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent for details
       on the request parameters.
    -->
  <requestHandler name="/spell" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- Solr will use suggestions from both the 'default' spellchecker
           and from the 'wordbreak' spellchecker and combine them.
           collations (re-written queries) can include a combination of
           corrections from both spellcheckers -->
      <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
      <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.count">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
      <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Term Vector Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermVectorComponent
    -->
  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the term vector component

       This is purely as an example.

       In reality you will likely want to add the component to your 
       already specified request handlers. 
    -->
  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Clustering Component. (Omitted here. See the default Solr example for a typical configuration.) -->

  <!-- Terms Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent

       A component to return terms and document frequency of those
       terms
    -->
  <searchComponent name="terms" class="solr.TermsComponent"/>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the terms component -->
  <requestHandler name="/terms" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="terms">true</bool>
      <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>terms</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>


  <!-- Query Elevation Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

       a search component that enables you to configure the top
       results for a given query regardless of the normal lucene
       scoring.
    -->
  <searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->
  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <!-- Highlighting Component

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters
    -->
  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap"
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter 
           (for sentence extraction) 
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex"
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">70</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html"
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<em>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</em>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>

      <!-- Configure the standard encoder -->
      <encoder name="html"
               class="solr.highlight.HtmlEncoder" />

      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single"
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the weighted fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="weighted"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.WeightedFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default"
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <!-- 
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator"
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- Update Processors

       Chains of Update Processor Factories for dealing with Update
       Requests can be declared, and then used by name in Update
       Request Processors

       http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor

    -->

  <!-- Add unknown fields to the schema 

       An example field type guessing update processor that will
       attempt to parse string-typed field values as Booleans, Longs,
       Doubles, or Dates, and then add schema fields with the guessed
       field types.  

       This requires that the schema is both managed and mutable, by
       declaring schemaFactory as ManagedIndexSchemaFactory, with
       mutable specified as true. 

       See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/GuessingFieldTypes
    -->

 <!-- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig#SchemaFactoryDefinitioninSolrConfig-Switchingfromschema.xmltoManagedSchema -->
  <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>


  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
    <!-- UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory will generate an id if none is present in the incoming document -->
    <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    <processor class="solr.RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="pattern">[^\w-\.]</str>
      <str name="replacement">_</str>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.ParseBooleanFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseLongFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDoubleFieldUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.ParseDateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <arr name="format">
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</str>
        <str>yyyy-MM-dd</str>
      </arr>
    </processor>
<!--     <processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Boolean</str>
        <str name="fieldType">booleans</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.util.Date</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdates</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
      </lst>
      <lst name="typeMapping">
        <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Number</str>
        <str name="fieldType">tdoubles</str>
      </lst>
    </processor> -->
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>

  <queryResponseWriter name="json" class="solr.JSONResponseWriter">
    <!-- For the purposes of the tutorial, JSON responses are written as
     plain text so that they are easy to read in *any* browser.
     If you expect a MIME type of "application/json" just remove this override.
    -->
    <str name="content-type">text/plain; charset=UTF-8</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <!--
     Custom response writers can be declared as needed...
    -->
  <queryResponseWriter name="velocity" class="solr.VelocityResponseWriter" startup="lazy">
    <str name="template.base.dir">${velocity.template.base.dir:}</str>
    <str name="solr.resource.loader.enabled">${velocity.solr.resource.loader.enabled:true}</str>
    <str name="params.resource.loader.enabled">${velocity.params.resource.loader.enabled:false}</str>
  </queryResponseWriter>

  <!-- XSLT response writer transforms the XML output by any xslt file found
       in Solr's conf/xslt directory.  Changes to xslt files are checked for
       every xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds.  
    -->
  <queryResponseWriter name="xslt" class="solr.XSLTResponseWriter">
    <int name="xsltCacheLifetimeSeconds">5</int>
  </queryResponseWriter>

</config>
```

Update now gives:

```
2017-03-13 12:40:31.307 INFO  (qtp1348949648-13) [   x:collection1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [collection1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={commit=true}{add=[videos_manager.video.34987 (1561758354571788288)],commit=} 0 123
```

If someone can explain what changes did the trick and why it could be usefull as Solr is a very heavy factory to understand.

Hope this help.

EDIT: It is definitly maxTime in autoCommit that slow down the updates. If I comment this line everything goes fast, put it back and upates are very slow.

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxDocs>15000</maxDocs>

  <!-- I suspect This make slow updates !!!!!!!
  <maxTime>60000</maxTime>
   -->

  <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
```